# Homebrew python installation options

Tags: python, installation, homebrew

I have read multiple sources online for installing python using Homebrew and all suggested this command:

`brew install python --universal --framework`

But when I tried to explore options for python, `--framework` is not on the list. How do I verify the framework gets installed?

```
brew options python

--quicktest
    Run `make quicktest` after the build (for devs; may fail)
--universal
    Build a universal binary
--with-brewed-openssl
    Use Homebrew's openSSL instead of the one from OS X
--with-brewed-tk
    Use Homebrew's Tk (has optional Cocoa and threads support)
--with-dtrace
    Experimental DTrace support (http://bugs.python.org/issue13405)
--with-poll
    Enable select.poll, which is not fully implemented on OS X (http://bugs.python.org/issue5154)
--without-gdbm
    Build without gdbm support
--without-readline
    Build without readline support
--without-sqlite
    Build without sqlite support
--HEAD
    install HEAD version
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Homebrew builds Python as a framework by default now.